# pyspark list of columnTypes

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am doing LDA using PySpark. For each row, I am computing the topics (topic-words that are a result of LDA) and appending the resulting list of words on to a master-list. The problem is that the list of topic-words are of `pyspark.sql.column.Column` type. **I do know how to convert this list of topic-words in to a normal pythonic list of strings.**

here is a snippet of code:

```
def map_ID_to_Word(termIndices):
  words = []
  for termID in termIndices:
    words.append(vocab_broadcast.value[termID])
  return words

udf_map_ID_to_Word = udf(map_ID_to_Word , ArrayType(StringType()))


tf_result = tf_model.transform(sdf)
tfidf_res = idf_model.transform(tf_res)
model = lda_model.fit(tfidf_res)

topics_df = model.describeTopics()
topic_words = udf_map_ID_to_Word(topics_df.termIndices)
# topic_words is of type <class 'pyspark.sql.column.Column'>
```

Any suggestion on how to convert list items of <class 'pyspark.sql.column.Column'> to a normal list of strings is very much appreciated.

My code is somewhat similar to what is here: https://www.databricks.com/blog/2021/07/29/an-experimentation-pipeline-for-extracting-topics-from-text-data-using-pyspark.html

```
`print(topic_words)` gives this: `Column<'map_termID_to_Word(termIndices)'>`
```

and

```
print(type(topic_words)) gives this:
<class 'pyspark.sql.column.Column'>
```

I plan to collect all these topic-words (for each row) in a master-list and then append this master-list to an existing dataframe that has the document. I have the code to append a list of strings to an existing pyspark dataframe. But, the thing is, I do not know how to get a list of words for each row.

**UPDATE** Here is the sort-of bigger picture of my code:

```
vocab_read_list = vocab
vocab_broadcast = sc.broadcast(vocab_read_list)

master_topics_list = []

for iter in cdi_grouped_df.collect():
  date = iter["date"]
  brand = iter["brand"]
  t_id = iter["t_id"]
  word_list = iter["final_word_list"]


  pdf = pd.DataFrame(data=[[word_list]], columns=["final_word_list"])
  sdf = spark.createDataFrame(pdf)
  print(f'SDF with final_word_list')
  sdf.show()


  # ------------
  # We must make sure if the list is not empty to proceed.

  # Word List: []
  # SDF with final_word_list
  # +---------------+
  # |final_word_list|
  # +---------------+
  # |             []|
  # +---------------+

  #-------------

  if sdf.count() > 0:
    first_row = sdf.collect()[0]
    fwl = first_row["final_word_list"]
    if len(fwl) > 0:
      tf_result = tf_model.transform(sdf)
      tfidf_result = idf_model.transform(tf_result)
      model = lda_model.fit(tfidf_result)

      topics_df = model.describeTopics()
      topics_df.show()
      topic_words = udf_map_termID_to_Word(topics_df.termIndices)
      print(f"\nTopic Words:")
      print(topic_words)


      # Now let's add the topic_words column to your topics_df
      topics_df = topics_df.withColumn("topic_desc", topic_words)

      # And extract your wanted values into a Python list
      topic_list = [x[0] for x in topics_df.select("topic_desc").collect()]

  master_topics_list.append(topic_list)
```

at the lastline (topic_list = [x[0]...]), I get this error:

```
PythonException: 
  An exception was thrown from the Python worker. Please see the stack trace below.
'NameError: name 'vocab_broadcast' is not defined', from , line 4. Full traceback below:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 4, in map_termID_to_Word
NameError: name 'vocab_broadcast' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

A `Column` object in (Py)Spark is different to a column object in Pandas for example, in the sense that it does not really contain the data itself, but is a representation of a column inside of a `DataFrame` which does contain the data. So in order to be able to access the actual data, you'll need to add this column to a `DataFrame` and then extract your wanted values out of that.

You can do something similar as in the example you linked:

```py
topics_df = model.describeTopics()
topic_words = udf_map_ID_to_Word(topics_df.termIndices)

# Now let's add the topic_words column to your topics_df
topics_df = topics.withColumn("topic_desc", topic_words)

# And extract your wanted values into a Python list
[x[0] for x in df.select("topic_desc").collect()]
```

A little warning: you should be careful doing this if the amount of data in this column is really big. Doing the `.collect()` operation in that case might result in OutOfMemory exceptions. If in the end you want to append it to a Pyspark dataframe anyway, you're possibly better off not converting to a list but just appending one dataframe to the other using the `union` operator or so. This of course depends from case to case.

Comment: I think I am missing something here. When I use your suggested code, I get an error "NameError: name 'vocab_broadcast' is not defined" from the last line: topics_df.select("topic_desc").collect()......even though I have defined it as vocab_read_list = vocab
vocab_broadcast = sc.broadcast(vocab_read_list)

Comment: Looks like you haven't shared all of the relevant code here, could you edit your question to add the code you're executing?